# Did Aerys II Targaryen father Tyrion?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I noticed [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31604/why-did-tyrion-lannister-get-his-name#comment59731_31604), and have to admit that I completely missed any references to this while reading the books.

> I doubt very much that Tywin meant anything by naming his child Tyrion. It is hinted that Mad Aerys might have fathered Tyrion, and it is common knowledge that Tywin despised Tyrion, but I have a hard time seeing his name being relevant for any of these things. – TLP

What hints exist, in either the show or the books, that suggest that Tyrion may have been a royal bastard?

Comment: Here is a good answer: http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/FAQ/Entry/Who_is_Tyrions_father

Comment: @TLP a summary of that link would be a great answer.

Comment: Well, no, it would be a copied answer. Its not a major theory, but it may raise the stakes a bit now that Tyrion is right next to Dany and has his own army of sellswords.

Comment: @TLP I think a summary is fine, particularly if you cite the source.

Comment: I am not really a fan of this theory, which is why I just provided a link instead of an answer. :) I think a much more interesting theory is that Jaime and Cersei are Aerys' children. Which, strangely enough, also explains Tywin's disgust with Tyrion, in that Aerys may have fathered his great and golden twins, but all he could manage was a dwarf that also killed his wife. It would also coincide better with potential wedding incidents, it would explain Cersei's madness and Jaime's potential greatness. It would also make more sense of Cersei + Rhaegar.

Comment: *"Madness and greatness were two sides of the same coin and every time a new Targaryen was born, the gods would toss the coin in the air and the world would hold its breath to see how it would land"* -- [Jaehaerys II Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_II_Targaryen)

Comment: As an aside, it would also give a nice continuity to the Brienne & Jaime relationship, in that Brienne may be a descendant of Dunk, and Jaime a descendant of Egg. (Dunk & Egg).

Comment: @TLP - Never thought of it that way! :)

Comment: @SystemDown Which part? :P

Comment: @TLP - Jaime and Brienne as the new Egg and Dunk :)

Comment: @SystemDown Ah. :) Well, how about the fact that Cersei's "valonqar" is probably not Tyrion, as she thinks, but Jaime? And that it might come as a result of Brienne tricking him into visiting UnCat?

Comment: @TLP - Does that make Brienne the young queen who takes her down? *mind blown*

Comment: @TLP the theory about Jaime/Cersei would even explain the incestuous between them, and explain Jofrey's madness... And it might fortify a bit the rights of Tomen and Myrcella to the throne.

Comment: @SystemDown No. :) Obviously the young queen is Daenerys. Doesn't quite fit with Jaime, since she seems a long way away from Westeros at the moment.

Comment: @TLP - Bah! Putting Dany (and Jon) in each and every prophecy is sooooo passe.

Comment: @SystemDown Well, that's just because GRRM writes his books too slowly.. :P If not, they would have been new theories.

Comment: @RenanMalkeStigliani Indeed. There are lots of interesting connections to be made. Although whether they actually support the theory is another question.

Comment: @TLP I was wondering where that spike came from :)  I hope you got at least a booster badge out of it!

Comment: @Beofett Well, no, there's no link between my reddit account and this one. :)

Comment: @TLP If you click the "Share" link at the bottom of a question or answer, it generates a custom URL that includes your profile ID.  Any click on that URL goes towards credit towards Booster, Announcer, and Publicist badges for you.

Comment: @Beofett Oh, I didn't know. :) Perhaps I'll edit that reddit post.

Comment: A related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71507/31029

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The theory that Tyrion is the son of Aerys II Targaryen mainly stems from two passages in the books:

First, in *A Storm of Swords* (Book 3) Tywin says this to Tyrion as a rebuke when the latter claims succession to Casterly Rock (emphasis mine):

> "Men's law give you the right to bear my name and display my colors,
>  since **I cannot prove that you are not mine.**"

This passage has also made it's way to the TV series (episode 1, season 3).

Second, in *A Dance with Dragons* (Book 5) Ser Barristan tells the following story to Dany about her father, Aerys II (again emphasis mine):

> "Prince Aerys... as a youth, he was taken with a certain lady of
>  Casterly Rock, a cousin of Tywin Lannister. When she and Tywin wed,
>  your father drank too much wine at the wedding feast and was heard to
>  say that it was a great pity that the lord's right to the first night
>  had been abolished. A drunken jape, no more, but Tywin Lannister was
>  not a man to forget such words, or the ... **liberties your father
>  took during the bedding.**"

There are a few other more subtle indications that some have taken as support for this theory: Tyrion's fascination with dragons, his odd hair coloration (pale blonde as opposed to the golden blonde the Lannisters are famous for), and narratively the fact that he seems to be on his way to unite with Dany.

However, there are several problems with this theory. Tywin's hatred of Tyrion can be easily attributable to the latter causing his mother's death during birth. Something Cersei holds against Tyrion as well. Doubting Tyrion's paternity could very well be Tywin lashing out at his son out of grief, since by all accounts Tywin was deeply in love with Joanna, and he isn't exactly the forgiving type.

The account of Aerys taking liberties with Joanna is also not without problems for this theory.

> Barristan's story indicates that Aerys did *something* objectionable
>  during the *bedding*. In Westerosi culture, the bedding is the name
>  given to the *first* time a husband lies with his bride (sometimes
>  witnessed by the feast's guests who have had too much to drink). So if
>  anything, this story casts doubt on the paternity of Joanna's first
>  born: Jaime and Cersei, not Tyrion.
>  
>  Sure, Aerys may have raped or seduced Joanna at a later date, but
>  apart from his known lust for her we have no evidence of this ever
>  happening.

Comment: You might also factor in that Tywin indeed tried to kill Tyrion (or failed to help him) when he was charged with Joffrey's murder. He intended Tyrion to take the black, much like Randyll Tarly forced his son Sam to take the black in order to remove him as heir.

Answer (score 3):

In the World of Ice and Fire (the Untold History of Westeros) more detail is provided, suggesting that Joanna mostly stayed at Casterly Rock after the bedding, but showed up to present Cersei and Jaime to Aerys when they turned six, and the king made some lewd comments that compelled Tywin to attempt to return his chain of office. No more is made of it, but soon thereafter Joanna is pregnant and gives birth to Tyrion.

More to the point, a great deal of detail is provided about how Aerys children tended to be stillborn monsters (more so as his madness worsened) and his jealousy over how perfect Jaime and Cersei were when they were born . . . and Aerys make's non-too-subtle comments about how he'd like Tywin to bring Joanna back to court.

There's a lot in that narrative to suggest Tyrion is Aerys's son, though how he could have raped her without Tywin knowing, or how he compelled her to sleep with him, is unclear. Perhaps he just threatened to have Tywin's head off if she did not? That is not alluded to, though, as far as I know.

Also, several of Aerys' stillborn children had tails, and it is rumored that Tyrion had a tail, but was lopped off at Lord Tywin's command. Martin is pointing very heavily at Tyrion being a bastard Targaryen.

Answer (score 0):

I would love for this to be true, but one thing that says otherwise is the eye colour: one green, one black. If the theory is true, then he wouldn't have the Lannister colour eye, as there be no Lannister genes in him - unless Joanna was a Lannister too, but that would bring up a load of other questions.

Comment: I don't believe in the theory, but Joanna was actually a Lannister.

Comment: This feels more like a comment than a real answer.